# Input two datasets into Orange Python Script widget?

Tags: orange

Is there a way to input two data tables (test & train sets) into Orange3's Python Script widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since Orange 3.6.0 the Python Script widget accepts multiple inputs of the same type: connect multiple data files to the widget's "Data" input, and access them through the "in_datas" variable (it will be a list of data tables).

Comment: @r.stiltskin If this answer is what you were looking for, consider [marking it as _accepted_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).