# Multiple Inputs to Python Script Widget

Tags: python, widget, orange

I've created a model in Orange 3.19.0, including a 'Python script' widget with 2 inputs (from respective 'File' widgets).

Data in files are `.csv` tables. Goal is to combine data columns from the two files, and output them from 'Python script' widget in **ONE** table

```
(File1_column1, File1_column2, ...., File1_columnLast, File2_column1, File2_column2, ..., File2_columnLast)
```

Referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50409137 and in light of 'Python script' widget catalog examples, with the following 'Python script' widget code:

```
from Orange.data import Domain, Table  
domain = Domain([attr for attr in in_data.domain.attributes  
                if attr.is_continuous or len(attr.values) <= 5],  
             in_datas.domain.class_vars)  
out_data = Table(domain, in_datas)
```

I get the following error afterwards:

```
Running script:

Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "console", line 1, in <module>       
File "string", line 2, in <module>     
AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'domain'
```

Seems input from `File2` is not recognized! (As it runs OK with only ONE input File, using `in_data`).

How can `in_datas` be utilized to recognize the `in_data` from each input channel? (`File1` & `File2`)?

Comment: if  `in_datas` is a list then why didn't try `in_datas[0]`, `in_datas[1]` and  `in_datas[0].domain`, `in_datas[1].domain`, etc.

Comment: as I know Orange already has widget [Merge Data](https://docs.biolab.si//3/visual-programming/widgets/data/mergedata.html) to add columns, [Edit Domain](https://docs.biolab.si//3/visual-programming/widgets/data/editdomain.html) if you have to change column's name, and [Select Columns](https://docs.biolab.si//3/visual-programming/widgets/data/selectcolumns.html) which you can use to change column's order

Comment: According to the [widget documentation](https://orange.biolab.si/widget-catalog/data/pythonscript/), there is no `in_datas`, just `in_data` ...

Comment: @furas: Thanks. Both work. However, the 1st option is better considering a "batch" of input files (FILE1, FILE2, ..., FILE_n) -not sure if this is doable in Orange?- with probably adding a loop in Python widget scanning all files. If so, how can the MULTIPLE OUTPUT TABLES (Table1, Table2, ..., Table_n) be dealt with for a following processing stage (requiring TABLE data inputs)?